# cmake: Extracting object library object file list

Tags: cmake

I am trying to get a list of all object files that are used for creating a shared library. My goal is to execute a command (objcopy) for each object file after compilation is done but before final link. I tried the approach of creating an object library and used the TARGET_OBJECTS expression, but I am unable to extract the names.

**CmakeLists.txt**

```
list(APPEND SOURCES helloworld_lib.cpp)
list(APPEND SOURCES 1_lib.cpp)

add_library(hello_lib_object OBJECT ${SOURCES})
add_library(hello_lib_shared SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:hello_lib_object>)

# Debug print
file(APPEND OUTPUT debug.txt CONTENT $<TARGET_OBJECTS:hello_lib_object>)

foreach(obj $<TARGET_OBJECTS:hello_lib_object>)
    add_custom_command(TARGET hello_lib_shared
        PRE_BUILD
        COMMAND echo "I would like to run objcopy here"
        DEPENDS $<TARGET_OBJECTS:hello_lib_object>
)
endforeach()
```

Debug print looks like:

```
...CMakeFiles/hello_lib_object.dir/helloworld_lib.cpp.o;.../CMakeFiles/hello_lib_object.dir/1_lib.cpp.o
```

Is there a way I can run the foreach() for each object file? I am new to cmake, so I might be doing something stupid. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `foreach(obj $<TARGET_OBJECTS:hello_lib_object>)` is ill-formed. You cannot inspect the eventual values of generator expressions at configure time.

Comment: You probably want to add a custom command to the `PRE_LINK` build event. See the docs here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events